# It is possible to have an combobox with two stores in Ext js 4.2?

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have to make a live search , and after hours spent on google I decided to ask here if anyone have an ideea how can I make an live search( using or not combobox) in Ext JS  but (the triky part). I have 2 data sets . One data set from one URL and and second from another URL.

I dont know how to start or how can I make the request when I type something in my search box to return small data set first and when is completly loaded second  data set ( is much bigger).

Something like when I type "computer" in search field in first block to show me some things related to computers (first request that have few data) after that in second block to show me more thing related to computer when request is over( second request lot of data).

I need this thing because in one of my request i have over 10 k product and i dont want to let user w8 until the request is done, and to show the other request that have fewer data. until the first is done.

I forgot to mention that i want to make both request in the same time and asynchronous.

Comment: you can try to modified your parsing data where you select the data. 
Just an idea, you can limit the data you parsing (first just set limit 1 to 10 rows, and you can insert an addition row of combobox which you set the value as what ever you want( for example  text: more..; value:-1) when user select this, you can set the selection with limit from 11th rows to the end of length data,

Comment: I am confused a bit by what you are really asking to do. First you say that "second block to show me more thing related to computer when request is over" and then you say at the same time and asynchronous. So which is it? Also do you want the results to be in a single list from both requests, or in two different lists?

Comment: in two dirfferent lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for exactly this kind of problem was:

Creating a store dedicated only for the combobox content.

When one of the two "source" stores loads data, they push the records into the combo-store.
You also have the reference between the records automatically, so if a record in source-store 1 or 2 is removed, it also disappears in your combostore- and so in your combobox, like magic! Here is the key, for pushing data on load in another store:
http://serversideguy.com/2012/01/31/ext-js-4-merging-store-data/

best regards, hope that helps, write if you need further sugggestion / info on this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is really vital, you can try loading up on memory when the application starts.

Create the stores you need on launch() of the app, load the data and the use it everywhere you want. You can do this on your controller launch() too, to your controller references and granulate this as you wish.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Blog',
    models: ['Post', 'Comment'],
    controllers: ['Posts', 'Comments'],

    launch: function() {
     Ext.define('User', {
         extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
         fields: [
             {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'},
             {name: 'lastName',  type: 'string'},
             {name: 'age',       type: 'int'},
             {name: 'eyeColor',  type: 'string'}
         ]
     });

     Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
         model: 'User',
         storeId: 'userStore',
         proxy: {
             type: 'ajax',
             url: '/users.json',
             reader: {
                 type: 'json',
                 root: 'users'
             }
         },
         autoLoad: true
     });    }

});
```

Comment: I understand , but if data is very big that will slow my app :-?

Comment: i want somehow to make 2 requests beacuse the main problem is performance and that is the reson for  2 data sets 1.with 10k products and 2.with 100 products for exemple and until first is loaded the second will be already there..(sorry my bad english if you dont understand) In short words : 2 requests for same combobox 1 will load quick 1 will load slow both in the same time :)

Comment: I understand your situation. I believe 10k of info is nothing for modern machines. You have to try this solution to know if loading the data on app launch will slow **considerably** your app performance. It's just a matter to compare times: _time with initial loading vs time with 2 request_ give a chance. It worked for me.

Comment: So you are saying that when my app lunch load all the data , and use it then when i search something in combbobox ? :-?

Comment: Another problem i have that , products are by type of user , so if are 100 users i have to load 100x10k so is a lot of data to load when app starts.

Comment: In this scenario, as you pointed, load data in the beginning is not a option. Perhaps you should send a different parameter when loading your combo data. This way you can limit  the data from your server without the need of two stores for your combo.